# autocorrelation for corCAR1() in gamm

Tags: r, mixed-models, autocorrelation

I am fitting a mixed model using the `gamm()` function in the `mgcv` package on a time series together with the `corCAR1(~time)`  for the autocorrelation. I have continuous time and unevenly spaced time intervals so I use `corCAR1(~time)`  instead of  `corAR1(...)` .
However, I wonder if I can check for autocorrelation in my model residuals just via  `acf(normalized_residuals)` , because I have unevenly spaced time intervals.

Do I have to worry about this and if so, how do I account for this computationally? do I need to impute values to make this work? Or is there a different way to check if a `gamm()` model with `corCAR()` accounted for the autocorrelation? Thanks!

I added the data below:

```
DF1<-structure(list(Y = c(7.552, 8.352, 9.852, 12.152, 13.452, 15.852,
17.452, 12.452, 10.752, 9.252, 8.352, 7.752, 7.352, 7.252, 7.052,
6.752, 6.852, 6.752, 6.752, 6.652, 6.652, 6.952, 8.152, 9.552,
11.452, 13.152, 12.952, 12.352, 13.652, 14.152, 12.252, 10.652,
9.152, 7.952, 7.552, 7.152, 6.552, 6.552, 6.652, 6.652, 6.652,
6.552, 6.452, 6.652, 7.152, 7.952, 9.252, 12.252, 14.952, 18.852,
19.752, 18.852, 17.552, 14.852, 12.152, 10.452, 8.652, 7.652,
7.352, 6.952, 6.652, 6.652, 6.552, 6.452, 6.552, 6.652, 6.552,
7.052, 7.652, 8.752, 10.252, 11.652, 12.652, 13.452, 12.852,
11.652, 10.652, 9.952, 8.152, 7.752, 7.152, 6.852, 6.752, 6.852,
6.552, 6.452, 6.552, 6.552, 6.352, 6.352, 6.452, 6.652, 7.252,
8.552, 9.852, 11.352, 13.952, 14.352, 14.452, 13.352, 10.852,
9.552, 8.452, 7.652, 6.952, 6.652, 6.752, 6.452, 6.452, 6.352,
6.352, 6.052, 6.352, 6.352, 6.552, 7.252, 8.952, 10.852, 13.252,
17.452, 19.552, 17.452, 16.752, 13.152, 11.552, 9.152, 8.952,
8.452, 8.352, 7.852, 7.652, 6.852, 7.652, 9.152, 11.552, 14.152,
14.652, 15.252, 15.952, 14.752, 13.052, 11.252, 9.252, 8.252,
7.452, 7.152, 6.952, 6.852, 6.752, 7.052, 6.652, 6.852, 7.152,
7.552, 8.552, 9.852, 11.252, 12.952, 13.752, 13.352, 11.752,
10.452, 8.852, 7.752, 7.052, 6.752, 6.552, 6.552, 6.252, 6.252,
6.352, 6.252, 6.052, 6.252, 6.152, 6.552, 7.452, 9.252, 11.952,
14.852, 16.652, 17.152, 16.852, 17.652, 15.352, 12.152, 9.552,
8.252, 7.552, 7.152, 6.752, 6.552, 6.452, 6.252, 6.252, 6.252,
6.152, 6.152, 6.252, 6.652, 8.352, 11.452), X1 = c(26.3424987792969,
26.3699989318848, 26.3199996948242, 26.3249988555908, 26.2674980163574,
26.5399990081787, 26.3699989318848, 26.7349987030029, 26.7349987030029,
26.7349987030029, 26.7349987030029, 26.7849998474121, 26.7849998474121,
26.7849998474121, 26.7849998474121, 26.7849998474121, 26.7849998474121,
26.7849998474121, 26.7849998474121, 26.8549995422363, 26.75,
26.75, 26.75, 26.75, 26.6474990844727, 26.6474990844727, 26.6474990844727,
26.6474990844727, 26.6474990844727, 26.6499996185303, 26.6499996185303,
26.6499996185303, 26.6499996185303, 26.7649993896484, 26.894998550415,
26.7049999237061, 26.7399997711182, 26.877498626709, 26.9049987792969,
26.7924995422363, 26.6849994659424, 26.8549995422363, 26.9174995422363,
26.7449989318848, 26.7049980163574, 26.7049980163574, 26.7250003814697,
26.7775001525879, 26.8349990844727, 26.8249988555908, 26.6749992370605,
26.7950000762939, 26.8549995422363, 26.7649993896484, 26.6199989318848,
26.6199989318848, 26.6724987030029, 26.7049999237061, 26.6399993896484,
26.6350002288818, 26.7150001525879, 26.6700000762939, 26.6399993896484,
26.6299991607666, 26.5, 26.4949989318848, 26.2199993133545, 26.2399997711182,
26.1074981689453, 25.9899997711182, 26.1875, 26.1124992370605,
26.0825004577637, 26.064998626709, 26.0149993896484, 26.0149993896484,
25.8799991607666, 26.0550003051758, 25.8999996185303, 26.0574989318848,
25.8899993896484, 25.8899993896484, 25.5974998474121, 25.7924995422363,
25.8549995422363, 25.8099994659424, 25.7974987030029, 25.6199989318848,
25.6350002288818, 25.6949996948242, 25.8525009155273, 25.7099990844727,
25.8374996185303, 25.3899993896484, 25.5799999237061, 25.5949993133545,
25.439998626709, 25.5450000762939, 25.3899993896484, 25.4149990081787,
25.519998550415, 25.5825004577637, 25.5825004577637, 25.6324996948242,
25.5825004577637, 25.3999996185303, 25.5450000762939, 25.5724983215332,
25.7150001525879, 25.7599983215332, 25.4599990844727, 25.7950000762939,
25.689998626709, 25.6100006103516, 25.6099987030029, 25.6424999237061,
25.6549987792969, 25.8050003051758, 25.7049999237061, 25.5149993896484,
25.5849990844727, 25.625, 25.6599998474121, 25.6974983215332,
26.0599994659424, 25.9674987792969, 26.2799987792969, 26.1199989318848,
26.1199989318848, 26.1199989318848, 26.2049980163574, 27.1025009155273,
27.4424991607666, 27.769998550415, 27.8499984741211, 27.8249988555908,
28.2799987792969, 27.9249992370605, 28.7000007629395, 28.6399993896484,
28.5325012207031, 28.9249992370605, 28.9249992370605, 28.9249992370605,
28.9249992370605, 28.9249992370605, 28.9249992370605, 28.9249992370605,
28.9249992370605, 28.9549999237061, 28.9549999237061, 28.9549999237061,
29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273,
29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273,
29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273, 29.1025009155273,
29.1025009155273, 28.7049999237061, 29.0174980163574, 29.0100002288818,
29.0399990081787, 29.2949981689453, 29.2599983215332, 29.2549991607666,
29.1349983215332, 29.2350006103516, 29.4375, 29.5599994659424,
29.4025001525879, 29.3850002288818, 29.5149993896484, 29.4300003051758,
29.5399990081787, 29.5224990844727, 29.5174999237061, 29.5474987030029,
29.3424987792969, 29.4500007629395, 29.189998626709, 29.189998626709,
29.189998626709, 29.0849990844727, 29.1549987792969, 29.3400001525879,
29.4300003051758, 29.5349998474121, 29.564998626709, 29.4274978637695,
29.3199996948242, 29.4324989318848, 29.4874992370605, 29.3675003051758,
29.1949996948242, 29.1974983215332), X2 = c(-0.661382887306292,
-0.713603641577777, -0.697034390888365, -0.683871486567943, -0.695303241824827,
-0.687824942421949, -0.762069107403866, -0.754447220494616, -0.754447220494616,
-0.754447220494616, -0.754447220494616, -0.762039773158054, -0.762039773158054,
-0.762039773158054, -0.762039773158054, -0.762039773158054, -0.762039773158054,
-0.762039773158054, -0.762039773158054, -0.754179790193758, -0.752373697667054,
-0.752373697667054, -0.752373697667054, -0.752373697667054, -0.756331538450329,
-0.756331538450329, -0.756331538450329, -0.756331538450329, -0.756331538450329,
-0.777863066933083, -0.777863066933083, -0.777863066933083, -0.777863066933083,
-0.786548912959555, -0.747600523162719, -0.776418423576957, -0.750324813677032,
-0.747198912394046, -0.74737923317013, -0.731517617218374, -0.687163219171754,
-0.706961034235684, -0.735617003686321, -0.76909309591312, -0.78935629791035,
-0.78935629791035, -0.786291317143823, -0.761807414179006, -0.662711141081837,
-0.738047859258564, -0.784969651085892, -0.826772982036145, -0.842466668605203,
-0.815509874665644, -0.723233741686759, -0.723233741686759, -0.688855742970708,
-0.722650909238424, -0.693777216429355, -0.759715171671963, -0.73624448247401,
-0.694543802727428, -0.703853985608692, -0.72406017656882, -0.759385756617125,
-0.746921127702489, -0.751106560912954, -0.795868540304523, -0.804724352702466,
-0.785402402678164, -0.760781241271038, -0.805125769678242, -0.781989108232488,
-0.803608283910917, -0.795438208498232, -0.795438208498232, -0.77329339871825,
-0.797284425022896, -0.783968588981806, -0.754671958381133, -0.790252432265644,
-0.83005440398501, -0.836489526959828, -0.835681504055955, -0.824482908695942,
-0.809154807458391, -0.809426415562343, -0.860471276656722, -0.845983686006989,
-0.943192543958938, -0.801735865771275, -0.783844016637946, -0.792406548298255,
-0.773549620984557, -0.81740935612748, -0.824036791819558, -0.970733356875071,
-0.974242316826758, -0.968622171367397, -0.882568042668447, -0.816964795789749,
-0.843615334127958, -0.843615334127958, -0.829393371791424, -0.843615334127958,
-0.833599811720012, -0.991673819155111, -0.93962902882149, -0.916183867167284,
-0.89416576059441, -0.942937278403605, -0.827918186956785, -0.849265891066003,
-0.810111842988144, -0.757383290753681, -0.755531970922105, -0.793535395667571,
-0.773135461989183, -0.797209930511133, -0.549966699512827, -0.755315629191252,
-0.633655038354613, -0.648980293241488, -0.599912992365375, -0.649929103688809,
-0.677976941813519, -0.702986210518213, -0.680244829257403, -0.680244829257403,
-0.680244829257403, -0.526533500780593, -0.790442601968874, -0.873822133917717,
-0.800135264792588, -0.784830241131085, -0.805893459073935, -0.885362876736644,
-0.836992732472436, -0.816831155588276, -0.958880764973503, -0.914308993353295,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287, -0.899043710796287,
-0.936767951839945, -1.05236117808989, -1.00260346456749, -0.898253151818657,
-0.967406305750456, -0.939999127684608, -0.90989562137593, -0.927359130615476,
-0.92301238675817, -0.869247973834648, -0.864510540818569, -0.836728570195734,
-0.936850564600175, -0.92524520323166, -0.894028587522116, -0.867884843431027,
-0.841310479881345, -0.828372233823954, -0.874035475874959, -0.953584999045546,
-1.08256880180383, -0.900333201890142, -0.900333201890142, -0.900333201890142,
-0.873054785878731, -0.924722195542873, -0.973323067961235, -1.04754180072968,
-0.946429551316996, -0.969238075150507, -0.959003553213918, -0.96466759823738,
-0.963258546383304, -0.962704773017868, -0.874146327258287, -0.863587876730798,
-0.83035867335996), X3 = c(25.65096875, 105.740625, 132.149390625,
252.192734375, 315.96515625, 309.211875, 336.7621875, 142.442390625,
64.3000625, 11.72234375, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
0.07678125, 26.053875, 70.11325, 175.364609375, 231.0311875,
339.5920625, 360.97421875, 343.3811875, 220.46, 200.57428125,
167.06690625, 68.39615625, 10.77265625, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 37.68984375, 86.248203125, 195.35584375,
240.834953125, 365.7034375, 318.69909375, 331.07371875, 279.6663125,
245.9095, 153.809765625, 67.072359375, 6.90678125, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 0.11515625, 28.97965625, 98.853046875,
185.5616875, 224.91103125, 323.73528125, 362.01984375, 278.563125,
275.10975, 186.72240625, 112.7433125, 41.172, 3.60690625, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 0.940125, 37.52675,
108.62803125, 200.10425, 293.5565625, 347.6883125, 369.3870625,
356.83975, 304.64575, 227.03103125, 128.76315625, 42.0833125,
0.96890625, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.39584375, 58.67871875, 89.692, 234.446203125, 285.07659375,
341.798375, 300.32903125, 233.9665625, 195.010515625, 108.829484375,
40.25109375, 1.24709375, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 68.779859375, 162.318515625, 251.51165625,
309.57640625, 372.859625, 351.5541875, 373.5023125, 313.62453125,
211.16465625, 133.4731875, 45.69975, 1.39096875, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 11.54965625, 82.34396875, 178.8371875, 254.715625,
305.691375, 325.529125, 303.70565625, 210.483578125, 121.76046875,
34.81203125, 1.42934375, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 12.787125, 74.82328125, 146.59603125, 269.9296875,
346.2781875, 334.0858125, 378.576875, 341.05971875, 259.195421875,
185.1875625, 91.40909375, 40.80746875, 1.86103125, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05,
3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 3.125e-05, 19.63634375, 80.761171875,
181.820515625), time = c(0.0500000000029104, 1.05000000000291,
2.05000000000291, 3.05000000000291, 4.05000000000291, 5.05000000000291,
6.05000000000291, 9.05000000000291, 10.0500000000029, 11.0500000000029,
12.0500000000029, 13.0500000000029, 14.0500000000029, 15.0500000000029,
16.0500000000029, 17.0500000000029, 18.0500000000029, 19.0500000000029,
20.0500000000029, 22.0500000000029, 23.0500000000029, 24.0500000000029,
25.0500000000029, 26.0500000000029, 27.0500000000029, 28.0500000000029,
29.0500000000029, 30.0500000000029, 31.0500000000029, 32.0500000000029,
33.0500000000029, 34.0500000000029, 35.0500000000029, 36.0500000000029,
37.0500000000029, 38.0500000000029, 39.0500000000029, 40.0500000000029,
41.0500000000029, 42.0500000000029, 43.0500000000029, 44.0500000000029,
45.0500000000029, 46.0500000000029, 48.0500000000029, 49.0500000000029,
50.0500000000029, 51.0500000000029, 52.0500000000029, 53.0500000000029,
54.0500000000029, 55.0500000000029, 56.0500000000029, 57.0500000000029,
58.0500000000029, 59.0500000000029, 60.0500000000029, 62.0500000000029,
63.0500000000029, 64.0500000000029, 65.0500000000029, 66.0500000000029,
67.0500000000029, 68.0500000000029, 69.0500000000029, 70.0500000000029,
71.0500000000029, 72.0500000000029, 73.0500000000029, 74.0500000000029,
75.0500000000029, 76.0500000000029, 77.0500000000029, 78.0500000000029,
79.0500000000029, 80.0500000000029, 81.0500000000029, 82.0500000000029,
83.0500000000029, 84.0500000000029, 85.0500000000029, 86.0500000000029,
87.0500000000029, 88.0500000000029, 89.0500000000029, 90.0500000000029,
91.0500000000029, 92.0500000000029, 93.0500000000029, 94.0500000000029,
95.0500000000029, 96.0500000000029, 97.0500000000029, 98.0500000000029,
99.0500000000029, 100.050000000003, 101.050000000003, 102.050000000003,
103.050000000003, 104.050000000003, 105.050000000003, 106.050000000003,
107.050000000003, 108.050000000003, 109.050000000003, 110.050000000003,
111.050000000003, 112.050000000003, 113.050000000003, 114.050000000003,
115.050000000003, 116.050000000003, 117.050000000003, 118.050000000003,
119.050000000003, 120.050000000003, 121.050000000003, 122.050000000003,
123.050000000003, 125.050000000003, 126.050000000003, 127.050000000003,
128.050000000003, 129.050000000003, 130.050000000003, 131.050000000003,
132.050000000003, 133.050000000003, 134.050000000003, 135.050000000003,
136.050000000003, 142.050000000003, 144.050000000003, 145.050000000003,
146.050000000003, 147.050000000003, 148.050000000003, 149.050000000003,
150.050000000003, 151.050000000003, 152.050000000003, 153.050000000003,
154.050000000003, 155.050000000003, 156.050000000003, 157.050000000003,
158.050000000003, 159.050000000003, 160.050000000003, 161.050000000003,
162.050000000003, 163.050000000003, 166.050000000003, 167.050000000003,
168.050000000003, 169.050000000003, 170.050000000003, 171.050000000003,
172.050000000003, 175.050000000003, 176.050000000003, 177.050000000003,
178.050000000003, 179.050000000003, 180.050000000003, 181.050000000003,
182.050000000003, 183.050000000003, 184.050000000003, 185.050000000003,
186.050000000003, 187.050000000003, 188.050000000003, 189.050000000003,
190.050000000003, 191.050000000003, 192.050000000003, 193.050000000003,
194.050000000003, 195.050000000003, 196.050000000003, 197.050000000003,
198.050000000003, 199.050000000003, 200.050000000003, 201.050000000003,
202.050000000003, 203.050000000003, 204.050000000003, 205.050000000003,
206.050000000003, 207.050000000003, 208.050000000003, 209.050000000003,
210.050000000003, 211.050000000003, 212.050000000003, 213.050000000003,
214.050000000003, 215.050000000003, 216.050000000003, 217.050000000003
), id = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2",
"11", "19", "22", "23", "24"), class = "factor")), row.names = 292:493, class = "data.frame”)
```

I know the time intervals are not that different but I expect them to become more unequal in future data, so finding a way to account for this would be nice.
the model is like:

```
mod1<-gamm(log(Y) ~s(X1) +t2(X2,X3), data=DF1,correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ time))
mod2<-gamm(log(Y) ~s(X1) +t2(X2,X3), data=DF1)
AIC(btt$lme,btt2$lme)
```

I would do this now:

```
acf(residuals(mod1$lme,type="normalized"))
acf(residuals(mod2$lme,type="normalized"))
```

But I think this assumes equally spaced time?

Comment: Provide an example of your data using `dput()`

Comment: sure, I updated the Q adding a data example